# Zoom and Blur an image on hover

Tags: html, css

I want to zoom and blur an image when hover over it. I am trying following code, it works somehow on the Chrome (not smooth transition, don't know why), but does not work on FF or IE although I have read that the blur should work with these browsers.

Also my other question is that, is it possible to zoom the image from the center instead of the top left, as it does in the example:

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/XR32V/)**

Here's the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="grow">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.grow{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.grow img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;

     filter: blur(0);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
    -moz-filter: blur(0);
    -o-filter: blur(0);
    -ms-filter: blur(0);  
    -ms-filter: blur(0px);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='0'); 


}

.grow img:hover {   
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;    
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: url(blur.svg#blur);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='5');   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add negative margins to keep the image centred:

```
.grow img:hover {margin:-50px 0 0 -50px;}
```

**or better still** use `transform:scale` (as suggested by Paulie_D) to zoom it as this uses the centre point as its origin for the transform by default.

```
.grow img:hover {transform: scale(1.33);}
```

FYI. The `filter: url(blur.svg#blur);` stops it working for me in Firefox because the file does not exist at that url in your Fiddle.

**Update:** Added working blur in FF.

See: [Updated Fiddle using transform:scale and working blur](http://jsfiddle.net/XR32V/9/).

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in your code that invalidate it

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='0');
```

You should leave that for a seperate ie specific stylesheet.

---

Here is an updated jsFiddle I got rid of choppy transition as well http://jsfiddle.net/XR32V/3/

Comment: Thanks but I don't see any difference, it still does not blur in Firefox or IE, as I asked above.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `transform:scale` and `transform-origin` instead of changing the image width.

See: [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/XR32V/5/)

```
.grow img:hover {   
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.33);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    /* add other prefixes as required /*

    filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    -moz-filter: blur(10px);
    -o-filter: blur(10px);
    -ms-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: url(blur.svg#blur);

filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='5'); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple JS plugin for zoom and blur an image when hover over it

[Get the Plugin](https://github.com/studio-marweb/mwzoomer)